# Can "travel it all" be used in this way?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

> Japan is very big. It would take a lifetime to travel it all.

I've never seen the phrase "travel it all." Can it be used in this way? If not, what's a better alternative?

Comment: It would be understood. I cannot think of an alternative but someone else may have a better idea.

Comment: We do say _travel the world_, but I think the verb is usually used intransitively - _travel round it all_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand what you mean but it is not idiomatic. Usually we use the verb "to see".

*Japan is very big. It would take a lifetime to **see** it all.*